# Estimated treatment plot in r

Tags: r

Having a dataframe as the one below, How can i get an estimated treatment means plot in r

I have tried using the ggplot

```
p <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = faca, y = res, colour = facb, shape = facb))
plot(p)
```

but im getting an empty plot for it. How can i fix this?

```
>data2
    res faca   facb obs
1   2.4    1    low   1
2   2.7    1    low   2
3   2.3    1    low   3
4   2.5    1    low   4
5   4.6    1 medium   1
6   4.2    1 medium   2
7   4.9    1 medium   3
8   4.7    1 medium   4
9   4.8    1   high   1
10  4.5    1   high   2
11  4.4    1   high   3
12  4.6    1   high   4
13  5.8    2    low   1
14  5.2    2    low   2
15  5.5    2    low   3
16  5.3    2    low   4
17  8.9    2 medium   1
18  9.1    2 medium   2
19  8.7    2 medium   3
20  9.0    2 medium   4
21  9.1    2   high   1
22  9.3    2   high   2
23  8.7    2   high   3
24  9.4    2   high   4
25  6.1    3    low   1
26  5.7    3    low   2
27  5.9    3    low   3
28  6.2    3    low   4
29  9.9    3 medium   1
30 10.5    3 medium   2
31 10.6    3 medium   3
32 10.1    3 medium   4
33 13.5    3   high   1
34 13.0    3   high   2
35 13.3    3   high   3
36 13.2    3   high   4
```

Comment: @Ben i updated the table to reflect the data columns

Comment: Your `ggplot` statement provides the data and aesthetic mappings. Now you need to add layers, etc. with `+` afterwards before displaying (e.g., geom_point() to show points). How do you want the plot to look exactly?

Comment: As it has been said above, just add `+ geom_point()` and see what will happen. You can also check [this](https://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html) to improve your plot.